# Grant reference on type

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, permissions, user-defined-table-type

What does `GRANT REFERENCES ON TYPE::dbo.myType TO public` exactly mean?

I found this statement together with every single user defined type we have. I wonder if this is useful or not. AFAIK this permission is required only for creation of new objects (e.g. a table or function) to reference the data type - so in case the regular database user will never create new database schema objects, does this kind of explicit permission make any sense?

Comment: [Permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191291.aspx): REFERENCES= The REFERENCES permission is needed on an object to create a FUNCTION or VIEW with the WITH SCHEMABINDING clause that references that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms191291.aspx), the `REFERENCES` permission allows the following:

> The REFERENCES permission on a table is needed to create a FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint that references that table.
>
> The REFERENCES permission is needed on an object to create a FUNCTION
>   or VIEW with the WITH SCHEMABINDING clause that references that
>   object.

There is no reason for a `public` user to have this permission when they are unable to `CREATE` or `ALTER` any other objects.

Comment: To assign permissions for a user to SELECT from a table, REFERENCES permission would not be needed?